# Unable to create webgl context for canvas

Tags: reactjs, canvas, webgl

I have a following problem. I have a React app and I would like to draw on canvas either on 2d mode or 3d. For that purpose I either draw two "2d" canvases on top of each other (required for static and dynamic contex) or one "3d" canvas. See the code below. However, the problem is that when I want to draw in 3d mode and try to access the webgl context it goes to the alert branch saying unable to create WebGl. However, if in drawImage3D I request the webgl context to dynamicCanvas there is no problem so obviously my browser is able to support webgl context. What could be the reason for this. I understand that for single canvas there can exist only one context at same time. However, for the "3d" canvas I only request webgl context?

```
constructor(props: MapViewProps) {
        super(props);
        view3D = false;
        this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
        this.dynamicCanvasRef = React.createRef();
        this.d3CanvasRef = React.createRef();
        ...
}

drawImage() {
    if(this.view3D) {
            this.drawImage3D();
        } else {
            this.drawImage2D();
        }        
}

drawImage2D() {
        
        if(this.canvasRef == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(this.image === null || !this.image.complete || this.image.naturalHeight === 0) {
            return;
        }
        
        const canvas : HTMLCanvasElement | null = this.canvasRef.current;
        if(canvas == null) {
            return;
        }
        canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
     
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if(ctx == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        ...
     
    }

drawImage3D() {
        
        const canvas : HTMLCanvasElement | null = this.d3CanvasRef.current;
        if(canvas == null) {
            return;
        }
        canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

        // Initialize the GL context
        const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
      
        // Only continue if WebGL is available and working
        if (gl === null) {
          alert(
            "Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.",
          );
          return;
        }
      
        // Set clear color to black, fully opaque
        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        // Clear the color buffer with specified clear color
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

render() {

        if(!this.state.view3D) {
            return (
                <div className={[this.state.mainStyle, this.state.borderStyle].join(" ")}>
                    <canvas className={canvasStyle} ref={this.canvasRef}/> 
                    <canvas className={canvasStyle} ref={this.dynamicCanvasRef}  onDrop={this.onDrop} onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
                        onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave} onDragOver={this.onDragOver} onClick={this.onClick} onWheel={this.onWheel}
                        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown} onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove} onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}/>                    
                </div>
            );
        }
        return (        
            <div className={[this.state.mainStyle, this.state.borderStyle].join(" ")}>                
                <canvas className={canvasStyle} ref={this.d3CanvasRef} onDrop={this.onDrop} onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter}
                    onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave} onDragOver={this.onDragOver} onClick={this.onClick} onWheel={this.onWheel}
                    onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown} onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove} onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}/>                                
            </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: Are you implying, that you're toggling `view3D`? Because you can only create 1 type of context on a canvas. So if you first did `.getContext("2d")`, then later `.getContext("webgl")`, then the second call would return `null`, as a 2D context was already created

Comment: Yes, I'm toggling the view3D. However, the getContext("2d") is only called for canvases pointed by references canvasRef and dynamicCanvasRef and the getContext("webgl") is only called for canvas pointed by reference d3CanvasRef in above code. Thus mixing "2d" and "webgl" context should not be a problem.